# Secure erase all copies of Aes encryption keys in memory

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to use AES for decryption and also explicitly clear the memory the secret key uses.

In order to decrypt something I need to pass the decryption key. When decryption is done I want to zero the memory for the key. Zeroing the memory of the key is easy enough with a call to the [CryptographicOperations.ZeroMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptographicoperations.zeromemory?view=net-7.0) method like this:

```
//just example key. The real key has been decrypted by an assymetric private key on specialized hardware. 
byte[] key = System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(32);

using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
{
    aes.Key = key;

    //use the aes object for decryption here.
}

CryptographicOperations.ZeroMemory(key);
```

But when I look in the [Aes implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f7a096dce6bb1d69b844b539678fa25ed7b8e20/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography/src/System/Security/Cryptography/SymmetricAlgorithm.cs#L82) in the .net runtime for the Key setter property I see that there is a copy made of the secret key using CloneByteArray:

```
public virtual byte[] Key
{
    get
    {
        if (KeyValue == null)
            GenerateKey();
        return KeyValue.CloneByteArray()!;
    }

    set
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(value);

        long bitLength = value.Length * 8L;
        if (bitLength > int.MaxValue || !ValidKeySize((int)bitLength))
            throw new CryptographicException(SR.Cryptography_InvalidKeySize);

        // must convert bytes to bits
        this.KeySize = (int)bitLength;
        KeyValue = value.CloneByteArray();
    }
}
```

Here's the implementation of the [CloneByteArray](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f7a096dce6bb1d69b844b539678fa25ed7b8e20/src/libraries/Common/src/System/Security/Cryptography/Helpers.cs#L46) extension method:

```
public static byte[]? CloneByteArray(this byte[]? src)
{
    if (src == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return (byte[])(src.Clone());
}
```

Is there a way to explicitly clear all the memory that handles the Aes secret key? Including all the copies that the .net runtime creates? Or prevent .net runtime from copying the key and only handle the one I have allocated myself?

Comment: I'll asume this code will be run in client side? If so, where do you save your key? Can be so easy to read from the compilated as the memory itself. Key should be thinked as to be recreated from temporary token

Comment: What are you trying to protect against? Whoever has access to the process memory can read the key, so anything you try is basically worthless.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Yes, code is running on users' computers. The Aes key is a one-time random key that gets generated upon encryption. The key is then encrypted using RSA2048 assymetric encryption. The encrypted key is stored on disk together with the aes encrypted data. Decrypting the Aes key is done by Yubikey hardware where the assymetric private key is not possible to be extracted. That's where I'm at now. I need to do secure erase of the memory that stores the Aes key. But I don't see a way of erasing all copies of the key since the Aes implementation in the .net runtime makes copies.

Comment: @PMF I want to limit the time the Aes key is available in memory. I want to do what I can to protect the users from outside attacks like rootkits that scan the memory or social engineering where others connect to the users' computer via remote desktop etc.

Comment: Cryptographically, that is pointless. You can assume that once it's there, it is accessible. You can probably get close to your goal by calling `GC.Collect()`, but that's still not safe to really clear the memory. The .NET runtime just doesn't work that way, but it _doesn't need to_, since there's no safe way to protect one's memory from bugs in the own process, anyway. And securing against attacks from different processes is the responsibility of the operating system.

Comment: @PMF does GC.Collect() clear the memory before returning it to the OS?

Comment: @johanrex GC.Collect() does not normally return memory directly to the OS, only if it finds a large free block after the collection. I'm not sure whether it clears the memory before returning it (I doubt it), but the OS will clear the page(s) before it gives them to another process. So it's not possible to get the data of another process just because one coincidentally gets a page that previously contained secret data.

Comment: Immediately after `GetBytes` returns and before *any* of your code runs, a garbage collection can run. Memory gets rearranged and old copies of the array may still exist. You're on a hiding to nothing thinking you can do this when working with managed memory. And note where I said it can happen - even introducing pinning or fixed buffers doesn't mean you're 100% safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Dispose` method will clear the `KeyValue` array, your code has done what you want to do, so you don't have to worry about it.

Here is the source code: https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography/System/Security/Cryptography/SymmetricAlgorithm.cs,196

Comment: That looks great. If I wrap the Aes object in a "using" statement like above, is the Dispose method guaranteed to run when it goes out of scope?

Comment: Yes, `using` guarantees that Dispose method will be called.

Comment: +1 but cause is the correct answer, however @PMF has right, you can track this in memory. That's why a lot of this are on a server side with an encrypted communication.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli In this case there is no server involved. This is code that runs on a user's laptop.

Comment: @johanrex so the action is futile

Comment: @LeandroBardelli explain please.

Comment: @johanrex nothing to add from the question comments. I can read whatever I want from memory, I don't care if were there for only 1 nanosecond

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Consider this scenario: The user has the secret in RAM. The user forgets to lock his computer and goes to do something else. A malicious agent uses the unlocked computer to extract the secret. If the secret had been wiped from memory as soon as possible this scenario wouldn't be a fruitful. I.e. wiping the secret from memory is a way to mitigate risk. Is this line of reasoning wrong?

Comment: If the user forget lock his computer, first thing I will do is install a logger to read the memory for the next time I've access, in the case the computer has no connection to internet, in that case I could do it anytime. We are talking about someone who has knowledge to do this. So, as someone referer previous, there is no 100% secure system, the thing is the result on effort/relevance of the data.